# Getting Sails.js to work with Node.js Cluster Module

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

I've recently started working on an App on node js using Sails.js framework.

I like the framework, and I want to use cluster module so it is more scalable.

How would I go about it? And I would appreciate any advise you have on it...

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's some information on clustering with sails.js

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/170